# read and writing from a file

Tags: objective-c

I know this may seem like a question that has been ask over and over again, but I am trying to verify that a file exists on the device (located in the supporting files folder) where the name of the file is "names.txt".

From what I've read the code below should work but I am continually getting "File not found."

```
NSFileManager *filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSString *path = @"names.txt";

if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath:path]) {

    NSLog (@"File exists");
}
else {
    NSLog (@"File not found");
}
```

Comment: is names.txt really the full path to the file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the full path to the file, not just the name.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSApplicationSupportDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *appSupportDirectory = paths[0];
NSString *path = @"names.txt";
NSString *fullPath = [appSupportDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:path];

NSFileManager *filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath:fullPath]) {

    NSLog (@"File exists");
}
else {
    NSLog (@"File not found");
}
```

Adjust this code to reflect the actual full path of the file in your app.

Comment: I changed my path to: "/Users/user/Documents/folder/folder/projectname/names.txt".
I'm not sure if there was more that needed to be changed, but that was the full path name from what I can tell.

Comment: @joshft91 Is this an iOS app or an OS X program? Either way, I don't think you want your code to have a hardcoded path to your home directory.

Comment: It's an iOS app.  And, right, I don't think that's what I want either but I was hoping to use a file to read/write.

Comment: The code I posted in my answer will work in iOS. As I stated, adjust as needed to match where the file is really being stored at runtime. The file needs to be somewhere in the app's sandbox, not in the project. And since you want to write to the file, it can't be in the app's resource bundle.